# google sign in not working aws sample app?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, google-signin, amazon-cognito

Changes required in **amazon web services sample app** to enable google sign in using new google  sign in API? 
Here is the GoogleSignInProvider code what are the changes needed to make this code work for v2 API of Google sign in

```
package com.amazonaws.mobile.user.signin;
//
// Copyright 2017 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates (Amazon). All Rights Reserved.
//
// Code generated by AWS Mobile Hub. Amazon gives unlimited permission to 
// copy, distribute and modify it.
//
// Source code generated from template: aws-my-sample-app-android v0.15
//

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.amazonaws.mobile.AWSConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.user.IdentityManager;
import com.amazonaws.mobile.util.ThreadUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Sign in Provider for Google.
 */
public class GoogleSignInProvider implements SignInProvider {
    /** Log tag. */
    private static final String LOG_TAG = GoogleSignInProvider.class.getSimpleName();

/** The Cognito login key for Google+ to be used in the Cognito login Map. */
public static final String COGNITO_LOGIN_KEY_GOOGLE = "accounts.google.com";

// Arbitrary activity request ID. You can handle this in the main activity,
// if you want to take action when a google services result is received.
private static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1363;

/* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 900913;

/** Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
private final GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

/** Android context. */
private Context context;

/** Flag indicating Google is handling an intent to connect (sign-in). */
private boolean mIntentInProgress = false;

/** The sign-in results adapter from the SignInManager. */
private IdentityManager.SignInResultsHandler resultsHandler;

/** The sign-in activity. */
private Activity signInActivity = null;

/** The auth token retrieved when signed-in.  It is good for 6-months from the last service
 * call. */
private volatile String authToken = null;

/** User's name. */
private String userName;

/** User's image Url. */
private String userImageUrl;

/**
 * Constuctor. Builds the Google Api Client.
 * @param context context.
 */
public GoogleSignInProvider(final Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    clearUserInfo();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Initializing Google SDK...");

    // Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public String getDisplayName() {
    return "Google";
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public boolean isUserSignedIn() {
    final ConnectionResult result = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        try {
            authToken = getGoogleAuthToken();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to update Google token", e);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public String getCognitoLoginKey() {
    return COGNITO_LOGIN_KEY_GOOGLE;
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public String getToken() {
    return authToken;
}

@Override
public String refreshToken() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google provider refreshing token...");

    try {
        authToken = getGoogleAuthToken();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Failed to update Google token", e);
        authToken = null;
    }
    return authToken;
}

/**
 * Initiate sign-in with Google.
 */
private void signIn() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final ConnectionResult result = mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onConnectionFailed(result);
                    }
                });
                return;
            }

            try {
                authToken = getGoogleAuthToken();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google provider sign-in succeeded!");

                ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resultsHandler.onSuccess(GoogleSignInProvider.this);
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error retrieving ID token.", e);
                ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        resultsHandler.onError(GoogleSignInProvider.this, e);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private String getGoogleAuthToken() throws GoogleAuthException, IOException {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google provider getting token...");

    final String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    final Account googleAccount = new Account(accountName, GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    final String scopes = "audience:server:client_id:" + AWSConfiguration.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
    final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, googleAccount, scopes);

    if (token != null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google Token is OK. Token hashcode = " + token.hashCode());
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google Token is NULL.");
    }

    return token;
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void signOut() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google provider signing out...");

    clearUserInfo();

    authToken = null;
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public boolean isRequestCodeOurs(final int requestCode) {
    return (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN);
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void handleActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mIntentInProgress = false;

        // if the user canceled
        if (resultCode == 0) {
            resultsHandler.onCancel(GoogleSignInProvider.this);
            clearUserInfo();
            return;
        }
        signIn();
    }
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public View.OnClickListener initializeSignInButton(final Activity signInActivity, final View buttonView,
                                                   final IdentityManager.SignInResultsHandler resultsHandler) {
    this.signInActivity = signInActivity;
    this.resultsHandler = resultsHandler;
    final GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    final int code = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context.getApplicationContext());

    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS != code) {
        if(api.isUserResolvableError(code)) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Google Play services recoverable error.");
            api.showErrorDialogFragment(signInActivity, code, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        } else {
            final boolean isDebugBuild =
                    (0 != (signInActivity
                            .getApplicationContext()
                            .getApplicationInfo()
                            .flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));

            if (!isDebugBuild) {
                buttonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Google Play Services are not available, but we are showing the Google Sign-in Button, anyway, because this is a debug build.");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    final View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    };
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(listener);
    return listener;
}

/**
 * Handler method for connection to Google failed.
 * @param result Contains all possible error codes for when a client fails to connect to
 *               Google Play services.
 */
public void onConnectionFailed(final ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                result.startResolutionForResult(signInActivity, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            resultsHandler.onError(GoogleSignInProvider.this,
                    new IllegalStateException(result.toString()));
        }
    } else {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "onConnectionFailed while Google sign-in intent is already in progress.");
    }
}

private void clearUserInfo() {
    userName = null;
    userImageUrl = null;
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public String getUserImageUrl() {
    return userImageUrl;
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
public void reloadUserInfo() {
    mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect();
    Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (person != null) {
        userName = person.getDisplayName();
        userImageUrl = person.getImage().getUrl();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample app and custom source code generated by Mobile Hub has been updated to use Google's updated API for Google Sign-in. Please re-generate your project within AWS Mobile Hub Console and try again.

Comment: No worries, actually I made the modifications myself then and made it work but I was facing token is null problem(but I was able to rectify it). Still happy to know that they have updated. Will check the updated code for sure. Thanks :)